# working in local bt unable to connect with server. showing error UCAExc:::5.0.1 Illegal char <:> at index 15: 192.168.13.30\C:\Users\Debabrata\Desktop

Tags: java

My code is below.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         String msAccDB= "192.168.13.30/C:/Users/Debabrata/Desktop;memory=false";
        String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"
                        +msAccDB;
        
        Connection conn = null;
        
        String user ="";
        String password="";
        try {
          // register UCanAccess driver
          Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        
          // establish JDBC connection
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        
          // use the connection to query the database
          // ...
        
          System.out.println("Connection established successfully.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("UCanAccess driver not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println("Connection failed: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
          try {
            if (conn != null) {
              conn.close();
            }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error closing connection: " + e.getMessage());
          }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working properly to access an mdb file locally but when trying to connect with server I'm facing the error

> Connection failed: UCAExc:::5.0.1 Illegal char <:> at index 15:
> 192.168.13.30\C:\Users\Debabrata\Desktop

Please solve it.

Comment: See if this works: `String msAccDB= "192.168.13.30/C|/Users/Debabrata/Desktop;memory=false";`

Comment: Having said that, I'm a little confused as there seems to be no access DB *file* name in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Given [UCanAccess passes URI verbatim to `File` constructor](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/git-code/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/net/ucanaccess/jdbc/UcanaccessDriver.java#l71) and that [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) accepts

> An optional system-dependent prefix string, such as a disk-drive specifier, "/" for the UNIX root directory, or "\\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname, and (...)

pointing to a **file** and given that [UNC on Windows specifies `\\server\c$` as a root directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths) I would change your connection string to

```
final String msAccDB= "\\\\192.168.13.30\\C$\\Users\\Debabrata\\Desktop\\somefilename.mdb;memory=false";
final String url = UcanaccessDriver.URL_PREFIX + msAccDB;
```

Additional emphasis of addition of `somefilename.mdb` to URI.

Comment: i changed as per your suggestion ,although username ,password is correct and file is there but it showing me the error  Connection failed: UCAExc:::5.0.1 given file does not exist: \\192.168.1.223\C$\Users\shibshankar\Desktop\SmartOffice.mdb

Comment: Are you able to navigate to that file via file explorer?

Comment: Yes..it's correct

Comment: Just to make sure, on the machine running your program you are able to type `\\192.168.1.223\C$\Users\shibshankar\Desktop` in file explorer and see `SmartOffice.mdb` listed there?

Comment: Previously permission wasn't given to access the file now now i am able to access the file . Thank you sir.